# updating two columns of a table

Tags: java, mysql

i have to update my table of two columns

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;

public class User {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String id = "QZhx_w1eEJ";
        String created = "true";
        String vmname = "pratap";
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        String dbClass = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate("update userprofil set created='" + created
                    + "',vmname='" + vmname + "' where userprofil.id= '" + id
                    + "'");
            con.close();
        } // end try
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // end main
} // end class
```

and this is the error log

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
    at User.main(User.java:17)
```

can anybody help me..

thank you..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need your JDBC [MySQL Driver JAR](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) in your class path.